# Angular Material sidenav directive does not work in app.component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-directive

I have an app with Material sidenav, the sidenav shows a list with links. one of these link has a directive that hide it if the user permission does not fit with the expected one. If I use the list inside my header component, all works fine, but  inside my app component the directive does not works until app reload. How can I fix?

**app.component.ts**

```
import { MatSidenav } from "@angular/material";
import { ViewChild, ViewEncapsulation, OnChanges } from "@angular/core";
import { Component, AfterViewInit, HostBinding, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import {
  Router,
  NavigationStart,
  NavigationEnd,
  NavigationCancel
} from "@angular/router";
import { OverlayContainer } from "@angular/cdk/overlay";
import { CustomizeService } from "./services/shared-services/customize.service";
import { FocusMonitor } from "@angular/cdk/a11y";
import { SidenavService } from "./services/layout-services/sidenav.service";

@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnInit {
  loading;
  customTheme;
  // theme: string;
  @HostBinding("class") componentCssClass;
  @ViewChild("sidenav") public sidenav: MatSidenav;

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private sidenavService: SidenavService,
    private focusMonitor: FocusMonitor,
    public overlayContainer: OverlayContainer,
    private customizeService: CustomizeService
  ) {
    this.loading = true;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getTheme();
    this.sidenavService.setSidenav(this.sidenav);
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.focusMonitor.stopMonitoring(document.getElementById("clienti"));
    this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
      if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
        this.loading = true;
      } else if (
        event instanceof NavigationEnd ||
        event instanceof NavigationCancel
      ) {
        this.loading = false;
      }
    });
  }

  getTheme() {
    this.customizeService.getTheme().subscribe(theme => {
      this.overlayContainer.getContainerElement().classList.add(theme);
      this.componentCssClass = theme || this.getLogoFromLocalStorage();
    });
    // this.sendTheme(theme);
  }

  getLogoFromLocalStorage() {
    return localStorage.getItem("customStyle");
  }

  closeSidenav() {
    this.sidenavService.close();
  }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<div color="primary">

  <mat-sidenav-container class="example-container" (backdropClick)="closeSidenav()">
    <mat-sidenav #sidenav (keydown.escape)="closeSidenav()" disableClose>
      <mat-list>
        <mat-list-item (click)="closeSidenav()"><button id="clienti" mat-button [routerLink]="['/clienti']"
            routerLinkActive="mat-accent">Clienti</button></mat-list-item>
        <mat-list-item (click)="closeSidenav()"><button mat-button [routerLink]="['/utenti']" routerLinkActive="mat-accent">Utenti</button></mat-list-item>
        <!-- <mat-list-item (click)="closeSidenav()"><butto [routerLink]="['/matricole']" routerLinkActive="mat-accent">Matricole</mat-list-item> -->
        <mat-list-item (click)="closeSidenav()"><button mat-button [routerLink]="['/sks']" routerLinkActive="mat-accent">Sks</button></mat-list-item>
        <mat-list-item (click)="closeSidenav()" [appCheckPermissions]="9">
          <button mat-button [routerLink]="['/packs']" routerLinkActive="mat-accent">Pacchetti</button>
        </mat-list-item>
        <mat-list-item (click)="closeSidenav()"><button mat-button [routerLink]="['/pc']" routerLinkActive="mat-accent">Pc</button></mat-list-item>
        <mat-list-item (click)="closeSidenav()"><button mat-button [routerLink]="['/rinnovi']" routerLinkActive="mat-accent">Rinnovi</button></mat-list-item>
      </mat-list>
    </mat-sidenav>

    <mat-sidenav-content>
      <app-header></app-header>
      <div class="main" color="primary">
        <div [hidden]="!loading" class="loader">
          <app-progress-spinner></app-progress-spinner>
        </div>
        <div [hidden]="loading" class="router-output">
          <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </div>
      </div>
      <app-footer></app-footer>
    </mat-sidenav-content>
  </mat-sidenav-container>

</div>
```

**check-permission.directive.ts**

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Renderer2, HostListener, HostBinding, Input, OnInit, TemplateRef, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from '../services/shared-services/data.service';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appCheckPermissions]'
})
export class CheckPermissionsDirective {

  permissions: number[] = [];

  constructor(
    private data: DataService,
    private element: ElementRef,
    private renderer: Renderer2
  ) {
    this.getPerms();
  }

  @Input() set appCheckPermissions(perm: number) {
    if (this.permissions.includes(perm)) {
      // console.log('ok');
    } else {
      // console.log('non autorizzato');
      this.renderer.setStyle(this.element.nativeElement, 'display', 'none');
    }
  }

  getPerms() {
    this.data.getPermissionsFromToken().subscribe(permsArr => {
      this.permissions = permsArr;
    });
  }
}
```

**EDIT**: log of `permissions` and `_perm`

on login before refresh:

[image]

after refresh:

[image]

**EDIT 2**

thanks to Sunil Singh for help me to found the issue: the `permissions` data are not available when I logout and then login again, the `app.component` that requires the `appCheckPermission` directive is not re-initialized, so it takes the old permissions data until browser refresh.

The workaround is service-based, I don't know how to fix with directive (the Sunil Singh way does not works). So I write a `permissionService`:

```
permissions = [];

constructor(private data: DataService) {
  this.getPerms();
}

getPerms() {
  this.data.getPermissionsFromToken().subscribe(permsArr => {
    this.permissions = permsArr;
  });
}

isPacksManagerEnable() {
  return this.permissions.includes(9);
}
```

the `getPerms()` method is fired on menu button click, then in the `app.component` I inject the service and call the `isPacksManagerEnable()` on the template:

```
<mat-list-item (click)="closeSidenav()" *ngIf="permsService.isPacksManagerEnable()">
  <button mat-button [routerLink]="['/packs']" routerLinkActive="mat-accent">Pacchetti</button>
</mat-list-item>
```

Hope it helps someone with my same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ## Issue

You have issue with `permissions` and `appCheckPermissions` in directive. You are checking for permission with Asynchronous data `permissions` which is not available at that point of time. Once the `permissions` is loaded you are not triggering the setter `appCheckPermissions` which is responsible to hide and show the link.

> ## Fix

It has simple fix, you need to ensure that whenever there is change in the `permissions`, it should trigger the permission checks.

#### Modified version

check-permission.directive.ts

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Renderer2, HostListener, HostBinding, Input, OnInit, TemplateRef, ViewContainerRef, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from '../services/shared-services/data.service';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appCheckPermissions]'
})
export class CheckPermissionsDirective implements AfterViewInit {

  permissions: number[] = [];

  constructor(
    private data: DataService,
    private element: ElementRef,
    private renderer: Renderer2
  ) {
    //this.getPerms();
  }

  private _perm;    

  @Input() set appCheckPermissions(perm: number) {
     this._perm = perm;
     this.doPermissionCheck();
  }

  doPermissionCheck(){
   
    if (this.permissions.includes(this._perm)) {
      this.renderer.setStyle(this.element.nativeElement, 'display', 'block');
      // console.log('ok');
    } else {
      // console.log('non autorizzato');
      this.renderer.setStyle(this.element.nativeElement, 'display', 'none');
    }

  }
   ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.data.getPermissionsFromToken().subscribe(permsArr => {
      this.permissions = permsArr;
      this.doPermissionCheck();
    });
  }
}
```

> Note : Code is written directly in `stackoverflow editor` so there could be typo or syntactical errors. Please fix yourself.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but this is not working yet in app.component until reload. in header is working fine. I need something to trigger reload

Comment: What do you mean by `reload` ? Do you refresh the page ?

Comment: when I refresh the page or reload app from console all works

Comment: Can you put the console inside doPermissionCheck() and check how many times it is being called and what is the value of `this._perm` and `this.permissions`

Comment: I have edited my question. PS: with a service fired on menu button click is working fine

Comment: try once with `setTimeout(()=>{  this.renderer.setStyle(this.element.nativeElement, 'display', 'none') }) `

Comment: In that case use an observable to check the status of permissions. Then load it with *ngIf